# UIView not displaying in given frame

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to create two drop down menu's side by side in swift. So far it consists of a UIView (created using a NIB) then two UIView's created in code that is used as a wrapper for the two UITableView's which will be displayed when the drop down menu is pressed. I have gotten the left hand menu (Leaderboard Menu) working perfectly but when I'm trying to create the 2nd menu the exact same way it is not displaying when the 2nd menu is pressed. For some reason if the x value of the frame is any more than 194 it is not displayed, my guess is that the 2nd menu is being added as a subview of the first but since the first's bounds is only 194 wide it is outside of the bounds to be displayed for that view. I will give a bit of code to show what I am trying to do. Thank you for any responses!

```
let leaderboardMenuFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 194.0, height: leaderboardTableHeight)
let rankingMenuFrame = CGRect(x: 195.0, y: 0.0, width: 92.0, height: rankingTableHeight)

// Set up leaderboard DropdownMenu
self.leaderboardMenuWrapper = UIView(frame: leaderboardMenuFrame)
self.leaderboardMenuWrapper.clipsToBounds = true
self.leaderboardMenuWrapper.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth.union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight)

// Set up ranking DropdownMenu
self.rankingMenuWrapper = UIView(frame: rankingMenuFrame)
self.rankingMenuWrapper.clipsToBounds = true
self.rankingMenuWrapper.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth.union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight)

//Init Leaderboard menu table view
self.leaderboardMenuTableView = DropDownTableView(frame: CGRectMake(leaderboardMenuFrame.origin.x, leaderboardMenuFrame.origin.y + 0.5, leaderboardMenuFrame.width, leaderboardMenuFrame.height+300))

//Init Ranking menu table view
self.rankingMenuTableView = DropDownTableView(frame: CGRectMake(rankingMenuFrame.origin.x, rankingMenuFrame.origin.y + 0.5, rankingMenuFrame.width, rankingMenuFrame.height+300))

self.leaderboardMenuWrapper.addSubview(self.leaderboardMenuTableView)
self.rankingMenuWrapper.addSubview(self.rankingMenuTableView)

view = loadViewFromNib()
view.frame = bounds
view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]


// Add Menu View to container view
view.addSubview(self.rankingMenuWrapper)         
view.addSubview(self.leaderboardMenuWrapper)

addSubview(view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is this line of code:

```
//Init Ranking menu table view
self.rankingMenuTableView = DropDownTableView(frame: CGRectMake(rankingMenuFrame.origin.x, rankingMenuFrame.origin.y + 0.5,   rankingMenuFrame.width, rankingMenuFrame.height+300))
```

The origin of the `rankingMenuTableView` should be `x = 0`. But as you are using the `rankingMenuFrame` to init the `frame` of the `rankingMenuTableView` its `origin` would be `x = 195`. This will push your `rankingMenuTableView` out of `bounds`.

So the correct way to achieve what you want should be:

```
//Init Ranking menu table view
self.rankingMenuTableView = DropDownTableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, rankingMenuFrame.origin.y + 0.5, rankingMenuFrame.width, rankingMenuFrame.height+300))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeap just realised this and was typing an answer! Yea that was all it was, i swapped both x and y to 0 and it works fine now, thank you for your help!